# PROBLEMA COM SQLITE - View com varios selects

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Tenho três tabelas que eu tenho que pegar um dado em cada uma para fazer um algorítimo na app, só que gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer uma view que me traga esse três dados que estão nas tabelas diferente. Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer isso pois nenhuma das tabelas se relaciona, logo com um `JOIN` não é possível.

Mas se um select não retornar nada  "0 row(s) affected" ele não traz nenhuma das outras tabelas, seria possível colocar um valor *default*? para que o resultado das outras traga mesmo que uma delas não traga valor algum

Os select's a serem feitos são esses:

```sql
SELECT PrecoBase FROM tbPRECOBASE WHERE Warehouse_Origem = "1" AND Numero_Item = "g";
SELECT * FROM tbPDISC WHERE Division = "BOV" AND Customer = "0" AND Customer_Type = "VD" AND Item_Number = "s" AND date('now') BETWEEN Date_Start AND Date_Finish;
SELECT * FROM tbPDISCQT WHERE tbPDISCQT.Numero_Item = "D53510B" AND 71>=CAST(tbPDISCQT.Quantidade_Inicial AS INTEGER) AND Tipo_Cliente = "JOS" AND DATE('NOW') BETWEEN Data_InicialData_Final;
```

> Obs: pela regra sempre a tabela `tbPRECOBASE` vai trazer algum resultado, as demais nem sempre.

Comment: Coloque o layout das tabelas !!! Acredito ajudar a responde sua questão, melhor, edite sua questão colocando o layout das tabela e logo após quais campos deseja trazer !!!

Comment: eu vou colocar aqui os selects, so que pela regra sempre a tabela tbPRECOBASE vai trazer uma resposta as outras vao trazer e as vezes nao vao trazer

SELECT PrecoBase FROM tbPRECOBASE WHERE Warehouse_Origem = "1" AND Numero_Item = "g";
SELECT * FROM tbPDISC WHERE Division = "BOV" AND Customer = "0"
AND Customer_Type = "VD" AND Item_Number = "s" AND date('now') BETWEEN Date_Start AND Date_Finish;



SELECT * FROM tbPDISCQT WHERE tbPDISCQT.Numero_Item = "D53510B" AND 71>=CAST(tbPDISCQT.Quantidade_Inicial AS INTEGER)
AND Tipo_Cliente = "JOS" AND DATE('NOW') BETWEEN Data_InicialData_Final;

Answer (score 2):

É possível criar views sim, segue link da documentação oficial do [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).

E [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243249/how-to-create-a-sql-view-create-view-in-sqliteandroid-and-query) uma questão similar no SOEN.

Exemplo:

```sql
/* criar a view */
CREATE VIEW VIEW1 AS
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.* FROM TABELA1 AS T1, TABELA2 AS T2, TABELA3 AS T3

/* executar a view */
SELECT V1.* FROM VIEW1 AS V1
```

> Não é necessário ter nenhuma ligação entre as tabelas, para utiliza-las, na `VIEW`, apesar de isso não parecer ter muita logica.

Comment: Creio que a pergunta dele é como fazer uma view com tabelas que não se relacionam...

Comment: @NULL, É só ele pegar o select que ele já utiliza hoje e colocar na view, acredito que ele já faça esse select hoje.

Comment: +1! Obrigado por ter editado.

Comment: mas se um select não retornar nada  "0 row(s) affected" ele não traz nenhuma das outras tabelas, seria possivel colocar um valor default? para que o resultado das outras traga mesmo que uma delas nao traga valor algum

Comment: @user7791, ai já é um problema, e no caso nem se trata de ser `VIEW`, o `SELECT` tem esse comportamento, não sei como contornar isso, espero que algum colega possa nos auxiliar. Fiquem a vontande para editar.